# Can I use a Portable Hard Drive instead of a USB stick to install Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive

I left my USB at college and have no DVD's around to burn too. Is it possible to use a portable hard drive in place of the USB to install Ubuntu to my HDD?

Comment: yes, but you'll have to format the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can simply load the image onto the hard drive, as you would do it with an USB stick.

Than boot from the HDD and select install Ubuntu. The wizard will guide you through the installation, where you have to select the correct *!* drive.